# PHP & GD : image splitting then Black goes Transparent

Tags: php, image, transparency, gd

Usually, transparent goes black on the questions I found over the Internet. But for me it's the contrary.

I'm trying to split a big image in several ones. It works quite fine but the main problem is that the result can contain black color which is turned to transparent... Please Help ! :)

```
// I get the image to split and dimensions
$source = @imagecreatefrompng('images/'."full_to_split.png");
$source_width = imagesx( $source );
$source_height = imagesy( $source );

// Setting alpha for transparency
imageAlphaBlending($source, true);
imageSaveAlpha($source, true);

// I will split the image vertically by height of 100px
$width = $source_width;
$height = 100;

for( $row = 0; $row < $source_height / $height; $row++)
{
    // I get the template image (a "part") which is a 100px height and full width of the source image
    $fn_d = sprintf( 'images/'."part_%02d.png", $row+1 );

    $destination = imagecreatefrompng($fn_d);

    imagecopyresampled( $destination, $source, 0, 0,
      0, $row * $height, $width, $height,
      $width, $height );

    imagepng( $destination, $fn_d );
    imagedestroy( $destination );
}
```

Like this : my parts have transparent backgrounds (so this is perfect) but if there is a (true-)black "spot" in the full image this one is turned to transparent.

If I use the alpha blending on $destination I don't have anymore transparency (it goes black).

I tried with imagecopyresized and imagecopyresampled... It breaks my nerves :p

Thank you

[image: Original colors]
Original colors

[image: Result after split]
Result after split

[image: full_to_split.png]
full_to_split.png

[image: part_01.png]
part_01.png

[image: part_02]
part_02.png

[image: part_03.png]
part_03.png

Comment: Can you attach a sample image to your question?

Comment: I think this must be caused by the existing `part_0X.png`. As I don't have the template, when I use `$destination = imagecreatetruecolor($source_width, 100);` instead then I get top and bottom black (no transparency). If I then add `imagealphablending($destination, false); imagesavealpha($destination, true);` I get the top black and the bottom transparent, in 3 parts, exactly matching the original. Can you also add a template image for testing?

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)
I uploaded the files for a try with my code the full image to be splet and my 3 templates parts).

Comment: Well, it seems that nobody can help me :/

Comment: I looked in to this a bit more but other events overtook me. I can't reproduce your problem as your description doesn't match the images you posted. `full_to_split.png` isn't transparent, it's black. And why do you have fully transparent images for `part_0x.png`? Will these eventually have something else or will they always just be transparent?

Comment: Well, you are right... you don't have to care about what is written on the image. The black part in the full_to_split.png becomes transparent after splitting this is the main problem.

My parts are fully transparent for other purposes. Images are added on the parts. Parts will change over time but at the beginning they are totally transparent.

Comment: It seems that nobody can help ^^. I have seen something about ImageMagick as an alternative but not sure I can install it on my shared server... :/

Comment: Really really really ?

Comment: Try removing the lines `imageAlphaBlending($source, true);imageSaveAlpha($source, true);` and adding the lines `imagealphablending($destination, false);imagesavealpha($destination, true);` after the line `$destination = imagecreatefrompng($fn_d);` (inside the `for` loop).

Comment: Already tried it as said in the main post :'(
"If I use the alpha blending on $destination I don't have anymore transparency (it goes black)."